# Marcar uma imagem com um ponto

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma imagem de um mapa e gostaria de colocar pontos nele. Como fazer?

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so], Rodolfo. Sua pergunta já foi editada por dois usuários, fechada por outros cinco, reaberta por um moderador, respondida por um craque e votada positivamente por usuários anônimos. Para completar o pacote de boas vindas só falta o voto -1, que deixo aqui só como lembrança que é legal explicar um pouco melhor o problema e sua situação atual ao fazer uma pergunta. O guia [ask] tem mais detalhes :)

Answer (score 8):

Se o que você quer é mesmo o que está na pergunta, usando PHP, uma solução é utilizar a biblioteca GD para isto, que geralmente já vem pré-instalada nas distribuições do PHP.

Veja um exemplo que desenha um pequeno circulo vermelho em uma imagem *jpeg* pré-existente:

`meumapa.php`:

```
<?php

    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg( 'meumapa.jpg' );

    $cor = imagecolorallocate( $im, 255, 0, 0 );
    imagefilledellipse( $im, 110, 135, 8, 8, $cor );

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Resultado:

[image: comparação entre o mapa original e o processado pelo php]

Para saber as funções de desenho disponíveis na GD, veja a parte relevante no **[manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.image.php)** do PHP.

Comment: Assim que chegar em casa, vou ser sobre a biblioteca, creio que seja isso mesmo, obrigado